# Transformar array de objeto em uma estrutura de dados específica

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, objetos

Possuo algumas informações salvas no banco de dados que gostaria de exibi-las em uma estrutura definida por mim.

Ao fazer um SELECT * FROM da tabela é retornado um array de informações, conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de exibir as informações da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As informações em negrito são apenas para identificar os valores das chaves do objeto.

```
[
{
    "IBX": "RJ1",
    "GroupName": "N/A",
    "ProductName": "Computer Hardware - Server Product",
    "POFName": "N/A"
},
{
    "IBX": "RJ1",
    "GroupName": "N/A",
    "ProductName": "Computer Hardware - Server Product",
    "POFName": "N/A"
},
{
    "IBX": "RJ1",
    "GroupName": "TESTE",
    "ProductName": "Storage Area Network Product",
    "POFName": "N/A"
},
{
    "IBX": "RJ1",
    "GroupName": "TESTE",
    "ProductName": "Storage Area Network Product",
    "POFName": "N/A"
},
{
    "IBX": "RJ1",
    "GroupName": "TESTE",
    "ProductName": "Storage Area Network Product",
    "POFName": "Teste_1"
},
{
    "IBX": "RJ1",
    "GroupName": "TESTE",
    "ProductName": "Storage Area Network Product",
    "POFName": "Teste_1"
},
{
    "IBX": "RJ1",
    "GroupName": "group_2",
    "ProductName": "Computer Hardware - Server Product",
    "POFName": "N/A"
},
{
    "IBX": "RJ1",
    "GroupName": "group_2",
    "ProductName": "Computer Hardware - Server Product",
    "POFName": "teste_2"
},
{
    "IBX": "RJ2",
    "GroupName": "TESTE",
    "ProductName": "Computer Hardware - Server Product",
    "POFName": "teste_3"
},
{
    "IBX": "RJ2",
    "GroupName": "TESTE",
    "ProductName": "Storage Area Network Product",
    "POFName": "N/A"
},
{
    "IBX": "RJ2",
    "GroupName": "TESTE",
    "ProductName": "Storage Area Network Product",
    "POFName": "N/A"
}
]
```

Segue o JSON para ajudar.

Abaixo segue o que tentei fazer, mas não obtive sucesso.

```
var IBXs = products
  .map(x => x.IBX)
  .filter((v, i, s) => s.indexOf(v) === i);

var test = IBXs.reduce((a, c) => {

  var product_name = products
    .filter(x => x.IBX == c)
    .map(x => x.ProductName)
    .filter((v, i, s) => s.indexOf(v) === i);
  console.log(product_name)
  var group_name = products
    .filter(x => x.IBX == c)
    .map(x => x.GroupName)
    .filter((v, i, s) => s.indexOf(v) === i);
    console.log(group_name)

  return a.concat({
    IBX: products.find(x => x.IBX == c).IBX,
    GROUP_NAMES: group_name.reduce((a2, c2) => a2.concat({
      GROUP_NAME: products.find(x => x.IBX == c && x.GroupName == c2).GroupName,
      PRODUCTS: product_name.reduce((a3, c3) => a3.concat({
        PRODUCT_NAME: products.find(x => x.IBX == c && x.ProductName == c3).ProductName,
        ATTRIBUTES: products.filter(x => x.IBX == c && x.ProductName == c3).reduce((a4, c4) => a4.concat({
          POE: c4.POE,
          ATTRIBUTE: c4.Attributes,
          ID: c4.id,
          times: c4.times,
          Price: c4.Price
        }), [])
      }), [])
    }), [])
  })
}, []);
```

Comment: Sua questão noa ficou muito clara, o Json que postou é como deve ficar, é como vem da Api? Não deu para compreender.

Comment: É como vem do banco.
Tem mais infos, mas para o exemplo é suficiente.

Preciso transformar esse array de objetos em outro array de objetos, mas como no exemplo acima

Answer (score -1):

Tenta algo assim:

```
arra.reduce((acc, ite)=>{
   acc[ite.IBX]={
     ...acc[ite.IBX],
     [ite.GroupName]: ite 
};
return acc;
},{})
```